# how to handle string list when it is returned by any BAPI using jco3.jar?

Tags: java, jco

I have a BAPI function to be called, which takes input a string and return a string list as output. I was using jco3.jar file in my java code but not able to find any inbuilt method which takes care of string list (String[]) as output parameter, though we have ByteArray/CharArray instead.

**function.getExportParameterList().getString("I_DOCNUM");** // it will work if the return parameter - "I_DOCNUM" is of type String only, but not working for String List.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Java Code:

```java
JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("mySAPSystem");
System.out.println("Attributes:");
System.out.println(destination.getAttributes());
System.out.println(destination.getRepository());
destination.ping();
JCoFunction function = destination.getRepository().getFunction("INBOUND_IDOCS_FOR_TID");
if(function == null)
  throw new RuntimeException("INBOUND_IDOCS_FOR_TID not found in SAP.");
  function.getImportParameterList().setValue("TID", "0A80351B1927589833E57997");
  
  try
  {
  function.execute(destination);
  }
  catch(AbapException e)
  {
  System.out.println(e.toString());
  return;
  }
    
  System.out.println("STFC_CONNECTION finished:");
  System.out.println(" Echo: " + function.getExportParameterList().getString("I_DOCNUM"));
```

---

Function Module:

```
INBOUND_IDOCS_FOR_TID. 
*"---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
*"*"Lokale Schnittstelle: 
*"  IMPORTING 
*"     VALUE(TID) TYPE  EDIDS-TID 
*"  CHANGING 
*"     VALUE(I_DOCNUM) TYPE  IDOC_TT 
*"  EXCEPTIONS 
*"      NO_IDOC_FOUND 
*"---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
data: wa_docnum like edidc-docnum. 
  select docnum from edids into wa_docnum 
         where ( status eq '50' 
              or status eq '56' ) 
         and tid eq tid. 
    append wa_docnum to i_docnum. 
  endselect. 
  if sy-subrc ne 0. 
    raise no_idoc_found. 
  endif. 
ENDFUNCTION.
```

Comment: Please add the entire signature of the function module to the question, including all relevant data types.

Comment: How did you define the EXPORT parameter in the ABAP function module interface? What type is it? As far as I know one cannot define array types as a remote function module interface parameter.

Comment: I have added the code segments please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDOC_TT is a table type. So you can access this parameter with

```
JCoTable tabIDocnums = function.getChangingParameterList().getTable("I_DOCNUM");
```

Then loop through the rows of the table and access the single field value of each row with:

```
String strIDocNumber = tabIDocnums.getString("EDI_DOCNUM");
```

or a little bit more performant via field index:

```
String strIDocNumber = tabIDocnums.getString(0);
```